# Save JSON data from an API into a database and cache the request, so i won't need to request from the API again - Node.js / Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this URL here: https://viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/json/ , that lets me retrieve JSON data whenever i change the given number on it(the number is unique). For example: 01001000 has its own data, and if i change it for 49140000, it will have its own data as well. **What i want to do is**: i want to save the JSON data into a database, and somehow cache/save the request, so if in the future i search for the same number again, it won't have to retrieve the data from the URL again.
I have this right now:

My **city.routes.js** where i make the request to the API:

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');

const cityRouter = express.Router();

cityRouter.get('/:cep', async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const { cep } = request.params;

    const resp = await axios.get(`https://viacep.com.br/ws/${cep}/json/`);

    return response.json(resp.data);
  } catch (error) {
    return response.status(400);
  }
});

module.exports = cityRouter;
```

An **index.js** to make easier to the server to import and use the routes:

```
const express = require('express');

const routes = express.Router();
const cityRoutes = require('./city.routes');

routes.use(cityRoutes);

module.exports = routes;
```

My **server.js**:

```
const express = require('express');
const routes = require('./routes');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.use(routes);

app.listen(3333, () => {
  console.log('Server is on!');
});
```

I can retrieve the JSON data that i want without problems:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMPM7.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via using caching libraries or using db and indexing on based of number for faster retrieval.

My suggestion:

If you need to cache for smaller amount of time lets say week or so prefer caching libraries like redis or memcache.
There u can do something like:

```
await redis.set(key, JSON.stringify(data), { expiry: '1W'});
```

The above code varies depending on library you use. But the idea remains the same you cache the data with key(Number).
And next time before making request you first tries to get the key from cache provider.

```
await redis.get(key)
```

if above value is present you will get json string of the desired result and dont need to make the network call.
If not present you make the network call and cache the result for future use.

In case of DB approach you simply make a get request via key to the db.

But do **index** the key in collection or relation when initializing the structure for faster retrieval.

Comment: Hello sir, thank you for replying. Does it save into a database? Cause it is the first time that i've heard of redis. Could you give me a more detailed code, please? So i can understand better what i have to do.

Comment: Redis, Memcache are very important concepts in any programing languages, I suggest you read about them it will be a great help for you in future. These cache are independent of DB, they are like seperate db from your regular mysql or mongodb etc.

When we store in these cache the time to retrive/update the key in them takes less time in comparison to DB requests. Also the redis etc are fundamentals for implementing queue and many other interesting think.
Let me search and give you some link.

Comment: Here you can read more about simple server side cache for Express.js app: https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/simple-server-side-cache-for-express-js-with-node-js-45ff296ca0f0 

If you would like to go with redis, then there's also a single npm module express-redis-cache that already implements the Express middleware.

Comment: https://livecodestream.dev/post/beginners-guide-to-redis-and-caching-with-nodejs/ This is doing the exact same thing you want to achieve, it shows installation as well on server for redis.

Comment: @mehowthe i'll definitely read it right now, thank you.

Comment: @RohitDalal thank you! This link will help me a lot, it does the exact same thing that i want to do

Comment: Welcome, Please do me a favor and accept my response as answer.